# Localization with playwright and POM?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm looking to localize current test cases to be able to run our tests on different languages. I have an already established POM structure to use which has it's locators on one language.

Are there any patterns or examples of how to set up a POM structure for localized tests?

The tests in playwright are already set up to be localized but some locators are not being found.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use Resource Bundle:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle